# Pivot Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Issue: I have 2.3 million rows of data that I need to transpose to about 90 columns for roughly 28k distinct rows. My main issues is my starting point is a view and not a standard table unfortunately I cant change the source of the data. Below I am attempting to use a pivot with a loop but doing one record at a time will take too long I am looking in to trying to process 10-100 at a time. I am looking to see if someone knows a better way to do this or some modifications I can make to the below code.

example:

no      field_name  answer
3604    DOES PHYSICIAN PRACTICE OUT OF MULTIPLE LOCATIONS?  No
3604    ARE PAs HANDLED CENTRALLY?  No
3604    ELECTRONIC PLATFORM UTILIZED    APPROVE RX
3604    ELECTRONIC PLATFORM UTILIZED    COVER MY MEDS
3604    IF OTHER, PLEASE LIST
3604    OPT OUT DATE:
3604    PA TEAM INITIAL REACH OUT COMPLETE: No

Result:

Doctor Number   Does Physician Practice Out Of Multiple Locations?  Are Pas Handled Centrally?  Electronic Platform Utilized    If Other, Please List   Opt Out Date    Pa Team Initial Reach Out Complete  Pa Team Reach Out Completed
3604    No  No  APPROVE RX; COVER MY MEDS           No

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

DECLARE 
    @SN INT = 1

/*

THE FIRST TEMP TABLE GATHERS ALL THE INDIVIDUAL [NO] AND ASSIGNS THEM A RANK, IN TOTAL THERE IS ROUGHLY 28K DISTINCT RECORDS

*/


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DocID') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DocID

SELECT 
    D1.[NO]
    , RANK() OVER (  ORDER BY D1.[NO] ASC) AS UN

INTO #DocID

FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT 
                D.[NO]

        FROM [CPRSQL].[dbo].[Dyn_Doctors] AS D
    ) AS D1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*

THE LOOP BELOW USES THE RANK ASSIGNED ABOVE TO PULL THE SPECFIC NO NUMBER INTO THE CODE AND GET THE DATA FOR THAT PARTTICULAR RECORD. ONCE DATA IS TRANSPOSE RECORDS IS THEN ADDED TO TABLE 
AND THE LOOP KEEPS ADDING ONE AND GETTIUNG THE NEXT [NO] TILL IT GETS TO THE MAX. 

*/

WHILE @SN <= (SELECT MAX(DI.UN) FROM #DocID AS DI WITH (NOLOCK)) 
    BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO [Finance].[dbo].[Information_Prescriber Preferences]

SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
        [Doctor Number]
        , [Does Physician Practice Out Of Multiple Locations?]
        , [Are Pas Handled Centrally?]
        , [Electronic Platform Utilized]
        , [If Other, Please List]
        , [Opt Out Date]
        , [Pa Team Initial Reach Out Complete]
        , [Pa Team Reach Out Completed]
        , CASE WHEN [Enrollment Date] = '' THEN NULL ELSE CAST([Enrollment Date] AS DATE) END AS [Enrollment Date]
        , [Do Not Send Referral Confirmation Faxes]
        , [Notes About Handling Pa'S]
        , [Refill Request Contact Method]
        , [Refill Request Notes]
        , [Spoc Account]
        , [Spoc Assigned]
        , [Prior Auth Contact Name]
        , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Prescriber Preferences)]
        , [Enrolled In Enhanced Pa Program]
        , [340b Account]
        , [Uses Cover My Meds]
        , [Important Notes]
        , [Back Up Spoc]
        , CASE WHEN [Date Updated] = '' THEN NULL ELSE CAST([Date Updated] AS DATE) END AS [Date Updated]
        , [Updated By]
        , [Does Prescriber Handle Their Own Funding?]
        , [Refill Request Contact Name]
        , [Refill Request Contact #]
        , [Prescriber Contact Name 1 (Prescriber Preferences)]
        , [Prescriber Contact Phone# (Prescriber Preferences)]
        , [Celgene Refill Requests]
        , [Iv Refill Requests]
        , [Prior Auth Contact #]
        , [Prior Auth Contact Ext]
        , [Refill Request Contact Ext]
        , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Prior Auth)]
        , [Prior Auth Contact Email]
        , [Refill Request Contact Email]
        , [Prescriber Contact Email (Prescriber Preferences)]
        , [Do Not Contact Prescriber For Any Clinical Clarification]
        , [Advocate Contact]
        , [Advocate Contact Phone #]
        , [Advocate Contact Ext]
        , [Advocate Contact Email]
        , [Notes About Coordinating Funding]
        , [Role At Office]
        , [Prescriber Contact Name (Prescriber Preferences)]
        , [Prescriber Contact Ext #]
        , [Do Not Contact Prescriber For Venclexta Clinical Information]
        , [Do Not Send Venclexta Referral Confirmation]
        , [Prescriber Refuses Pa Follow Up]
        , [Psd Pilot Prescriber]
        , [Business Hours]
        , [Communication Distribution Notes]
        , [Send All First Shipments To Mdo - If Yes, Set Up Delivery Ticket.]
        , [Do Not Send Xpovio Referral Confirmation]
        , [Celgene Auth Requests]
        , [Shipping Instructions]
        , [How Many Days Prior Should The Team Follow Up For Refill?]
        , [Best Time To Call]
        , [Rd Assigned]
        , [Back Up Rd Assigned]
        , [Regional Director (Field)]
        , [Field Sales Director]
        , [Alternate Location Notes]
        , [Alternate Location]
        , [Days At Alternate Location]
        , [Alternate Location Fax#]
        , [Alternate Location Ph#]
        , [Alternative Confirmation Fax#]
        , [Alternative Confirmation Email]
        , [Onboarding Preferred Method Of Contact]
        , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Name]
        , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Email]
        , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Phone#]
        , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Ext#]
        , [Rph Preferred Method Of Contact]
        , [Prescriber Contact Phone# (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
        , [Prescriber Contact Email (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
        , [Prescriber Contact Name (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
        , [Prescriber Contact Ext#]
        , [If Pa Team Can Contact Prescriber, How Does Prescriber Want To Receive Cmm Key?]
        , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Outbound Scheduling)]
        , [If Prescriber Handles Their Own Funding, Please Clarify Specifically What They Prefer To Handle]
        , [Only Rd Can Communicate Prior Auth Information]
        , [Prior Auth Contact Fax#]
        , [Send Fax Confirmation Via Fax & Email]
        , [Does Prescriber Want To Be Notified Prior To Transfer?]
        , [Does Prescriber Have Specific Contacts At Other Sp'S] AS [Does Prescriber Have Specific Contacts At Other Sp's]
        , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Transfers)]
        , [Transfer Notes]
        , [Prescriber Wants Notified  Prior To Contacting Patient If Patient Copay Is Over]
        , [Advocates Preferred Method Of Contact]
        , [Notes About Clinical Clarifications]
        , [Notes About Fax Confirmation]
        , GETDATE() AS [LoadDate]


FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT 
                D2.[Doctor Number]
                , D2.[field_name]
                , COALESCE(D2.[Combined Answers], D2.[answer]) AS [Answer]

        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT 
                        [no] AS [Doctor Number]
                        ,[field_key]
                        , [Finance].[dbo].[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital](REPLACE(CASE 
                            WHEN [field_key] = 792 THEN 'Preferred Method of Contact (Prescriber Preferences):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 894 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Name 1 (Prescriber Preferences):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 895 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Phone# (Prescriber Preferences):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 911 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Email (Prescriber Preferences):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 923 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Name (Prescriber Preferences):'

                            WHEN [field_key] = 2262 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Phone# (Rx Set Up/RPH/Clinical Clarification):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 2263 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Email (Rx Set Up/RPH/Clinical Clarification):'
                            WHEN [field_key] = 2264 THEN 'Prescriber Contact Name (Rx Set Up/RPH/Clinical Clarification):'

                            WHEN [field_key] = 2331 THEN 'Preferred Method of Contact (Transfers):'

                            WHEN [field_key] = 908 THEN 'Preferred Method of Contact (Prior Auth):'

                            WHEN [field_key] = 2269 THEN 'Preferred Method of Contact (Outbound Scheduling):'

                        ELSE [field_name]
                        END,':',''))  AS [field_name]
                        ,[field_type]
                        ,[mask]
                        , [answer]
                        , LTRIM(STUFF(
                                (SELECT 
                                    '; ' + D1.[answer]

                                FROM [CPRSQL].[dbo].[Dyn_Doctors] AS D1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                                WHERE D1.[field_type] = 'MC, Multiple Answers'
                                    AND D1.[no] = D.[no]
                                    AND D1.[field_key] = D.[field_key]

                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS [Combined Answers]

                  FROM [CPRSQL].[dbo].[Dyn_Doctors] AS D
                  WHERE [NO] =
                                (
                                    SELECT 
                                        DI.[no]
                                    FROM #DocID AS DI WITH(NOLOCK)
                                    WHERE DI.UN = @SN
                                )   
            ) AS D2 
    ) AS Base

    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(answer)
        FOR field_name IN 
            (
                [Does Physician Practice Out Of Multiple Locations?]
                , [Are Pas Handled Centrally?]
                , [Electronic Platform Utilized]
                , [If Other, Please List]
                , [Opt Out Date]
                , [Pa Team Initial Reach Out Complete]
                , [Pa Team Reach Out Completed]
                , [Enrollment Date]
                , [Do Not Send Referral Confirmation Faxes]
                , [Notes About Handling Pa'S]
                , [Refill Request Contact Method]
                , [Refill Request Notes]
                , [Spoc Account]
                , [Spoc Assigned]
                , [Prior Auth Contact Name]
                , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Prescriber Preferences)]
                , [Enrolled In Enhanced Pa Program]
                , [340b Account]
                , [Uses Cover My Meds]
                , [Important Notes]
                , [Back Up Spoc]
                , [Date Updated]
                , [Updated By]
                , [Does Prescriber Handle Their Own Funding?]
                , [Refill Request Contact Name]
                , [Refill Request Contact #]
                , [Prescriber Contact Name 1 (Prescriber Preferences)]
                , [Prescriber Contact Phone# (Prescriber Preferences)]
                , [Celgene Refill Requests]
                , [Iv Refill Requests]
                , [Prior Auth Contact #]
                , [Prior Auth Contact Ext]
                , [Refill Request Contact Ext]
                , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Prior Auth)]
                , [Prior Auth Contact Email]
                , [Refill Request Contact Email]
                , [Prescriber Contact Email (Prescriber Preferences)]
                , [Do Not Contact Prescriber For Any Clinical Clarification]
                , [Advocate Contact]
                , [Advocate Contact Phone #]
                , [Advocate Contact Ext]
                , [Advocate Contact Email]
                , [Notes About Coordinating Funding]
                , [Role At Office]
                , [Prescriber Contact Name (Prescriber Preferences)]
                , [Prescriber Contact Ext #]
                , [Do Not Contact Prescriber For Venclexta Clinical Information]
                , [Do Not Send Venclexta Referral Confirmation]
                , [Prescriber Refuses Pa Follow Up]
                , [Psd Pilot Prescriber]
                , [Business Hours]
                , [Communication Distribution Notes]
                , [Send All First Shipments To Mdo - If Yes, Set Up Delivery Ticket.]
                , [Do Not Send Xpovio Referral Confirmation]
                , [Celgene Auth Requests]
                , [Shipping Instructions]
                , [How Many Days Prior Should The Team Follow Up For Refill?]
                , [Best Time To Call]
                , [Rd Assigned]
                , [Back Up Rd Assigned]
                , [Regional Director (Field)]
                , [Field Sales Director]
                , [Alternate Location Notes]
                , [Alternate Location]
                , [Days At Alternate Location]
                , [Alternate Location Fax#]
                , [Alternate Location Ph#]
                , [Alternative Confirmation Fax#]
                , [Alternative Confirmation Email]
                , [Onboarding Preferred Method Of Contact]
                , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Name]
                , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Email]
                , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Phone#]
                , [Onboarding Prescriber Contact Ext#]
                , [Rph Preferred Method Of Contact]
                , [Prescriber Contact Phone# (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
                , [Prescriber Contact Email (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
                , [Prescriber Contact Name (Rx Set Up/Rph/Clinical Clarification)]
                , [Prescriber Contact Ext#]
                , [If Pa Team Can Contact Prescriber, How Does Prescriber Want To Receive Cmm Key?]
                , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Outbound Scheduling)]
                , [If Prescriber Handles Their Own Funding, Please Clarify Specifically What They Prefer To Handle]
                , [Only Rd Can Communicate Prior Auth Information]
                , [Prior Auth Contact Fax#]
                , [Send Fax Confirmation Via Fax & Email]
                , [Does Prescriber Want To Be Notified Prior To Transfer?]
                , [Does Prescriber Have Specific Contacts At Other Sp'S]
                , [Preferred Method Of Contact (Transfers)]
                , [Transfer Notes]
                , [Prescriber Wants Notified  Prior To Contacting Patient If Patient Copay Is Over]
                , [Advocates Preferred Method Of Contact]
                , [Notes About Clinical Clarifications]
                , [Notes About Fax Confirmation]


             )
    ) AS PT

OPTION (RECOMPILE)


        SET @SN = @SN + 1
    END
```

Comment: *"I am looking to see if someone knows a better way"* Getting rid of the loop would be the first thing. SQL is a set based language and you should be using set based methods. Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Also, you say you want to "transpose"  data that has 90 columns, and 28,000~ rows. "Transposing" normally means "rotating" the data 90 degrees; so the rows become columns and the columns become rows. From the tag, [tag:transpose] you have used: *"Transposition is an operation that applies to matrices wherein the rows and columns are swapped"*. That would mean you would have 28,000~ columns; I somewhat doubt that is your goal here.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? With 2017 and newer, `STRING_AGG()` will make that `STUFF/FOR XML` bit much cleaner and faster.

Comment: I am on 2016 unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for all the insights on correct terminology

Comment: Did you instead try using CROSS APPLY? PIVOT doesn't really provide anything special for you here.